# Lost Focus Event Strategy in MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I’m developing a WPF application with MVVM design pattern which makes use of the MVVM Light Toolkit. Currently I have a scenario like this.

[image]

I’m binding an Items Control to an Organization collection.

1. An Organization comprised of Organization Name and a List.
2. A project comprised of Project Name, List and New Employee
3. An Employee comprised of Emp Name, Contact No and Email

[image]

Here Employee itself is a user control which is reused in Existing and New Employee data.

User can update existing employee’s details (i.e. List) on every control's Lost Focus event. When it comes to adding a new employee, I handled the situation using user control **Lost Focus** Event. So on user control lost focus event using MVVM Light Toolkit **EventToCommand**, I’m passing EventArgs to View Model and then finding the Original Source from **EventArgs**(or traverse through the visual tree) to identify whether it’s to be inserted or not by checking whether the focus is within same user control using IsKeyBoardFocusWithin property.

Is this is the right implementation on MVVM pattern?

Also by doing the above approach I have to:

1. Traverse through the visual tree or to get the Original Source
   from EventArgs I have to make reference to System.Windows.Controls.
2. when it comes to unit testing, it would be more difficult to
       mock the EventArgs.

So is there any better MVVM approach to handle this scenario…

Comment: Is your new employee bound to an object in the view model?  Is the lost focus event ties into all employeeUserControls, or is there a unique lost focus command for just the new employee user control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself traversing through the Visual Tree should be avoided in the ViewModel

So an alternative to this approach could be using a [Behavior - Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html)

- So let's assume you create a Behavior called `AddNewEmployeeBehavior`
- Next add a `RelayCommand<Employee> AddNewEmployeeCommand;` to your VM.
- Create a DP of type `RelayCommand<Employee>` in `AddNewEmployeeBehavior`
- In the View bind the DP of the Behavior to `AddNewEmployeeCommand`
- Now in `AddNewEmployeeBehavior` do what you were doing in the VM to check if a new item needs to be added to the `List<Employee>`
- When new item is required to be added to the List kept in the VM / Model, Invoke the DP Command in the Behavior passing in the new Employee details wrapped into an `Employee` object.
- In the VM, create your RelayCommand accordingly to append it's invoked-with argument to the `List<Employee>`

Now with this approach, you do not have any `EventToCommand` stuff in the View. You simply have a Behavior taking a Command as a DP and have it invoke the Command when required based on the View only conditions you have.

As for unit-testing, that's very simple now cos all you have is a RelayCommand which you can invoke when desired in your unit-test.

This will hold as a MVVM solution since you no longer have any View related logic in your VM and the Behavior handles it for the View.

VM -> ViewModel

DP -> [Dependency Property](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that we can handle a situation like this with Attached Behavior. Let me workout a sample and get back to you soon. 
Just have a small concern on keeping the business logic (i.e. to add an employee or not) in the behavior class which is a part of the view.

Comment: @Dennis business logic should not be part of the Behavior. Behavior's purpose here is to just convey to the ViewModel / Model "Hey I want to add a new row" which the business logic in the VM should choose to accept and add or reject and notify the View accordingly via an ErrorTemplate or so.

Comment: @Dennis as I mentioned in my answer the Behavior should only deal with View related logic. Now provided you comply with this, testing will again be just as I mentioned. You do not need the behavior in your Unit tests for testing business logic. Just try invoking the Command exposed by the VM in different ways and validate your business logic which is in the VM